# What's the different among the concepts Probability, Possibility and Belief?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can you please explain the difference among the concepts Probability, Possibility and Belief through some simple examples?

Answer (score 5):

Belief is something you believe in, for example : You believing this question will get many answers and end up as a popular question.

Probability is the chance that something will happen, for example: The probability that your question will suffer from downvotes (and maybe put On Hold or Off topic) is pretty higher than your belief.

Possibilities are all the possible things that could happen to your question, each possibility has its own probability. For example the probability of this question being flagged is much higher than the probability of it falling into the MOST POPULAR CATEGORY.

Comment: +1 for the self-reference (although the existence of your answer modifies the prior on the fate of the question).

Comment: @Tharindu Possibility has another concept called Necessity. Can you pl include that also in this example?

Comment: "Possibility has another concept called Necessity." Heee? *Possibility* **has** a *concept*? Has it?

Comment: I don't understand this new concept :)

Comment: @Nadaraj , I wrote what I know :) You can add that as your own answer since I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Did , Can you restate what you mean by "modifies the prior on the fate of the question" , I didn't quite get that :) .

Comment: I am sure you did get it perfectly but here we go: questions with highly upvoted answers are more rarely closed.

Comment: @Did "possibility theory uses two concepts, the possibility and the necessity of the event. " - Wikipedia. you can rfer this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possibility_theory

Comment: @Did Thank you :) It's a compliment :) Thank you for thinking my answer is good :)

Comment: @Nadaraj Thanks for the link. Comment: "Possibility" $\ne$ "Possibility theory", Possibility *theory* may have concepts, but not "Possibility" (I am skipping here the fact that philosophers would probably object to this very loose use of the word "concept"). How are we supposed to guess you are referring to the latter when using the former? Furthermore, you should be aware that the theory described on the WP page you linked to is not exactly universally in use in maths departments...

Comment: @Did, Ya, you are correct. This is not a universally accepted theory. This is proposed by Dubois & Prade. It is  mostly used in Fuzzy Logic. If you have interest you can refer this site http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Possibility_theory

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical terms, probability and possibility are a number from 0 to 1 that something will happen.  It is probable that the sun will come up tomorrow.  It is possible that I will win the lottery.

There is a mathematical word for belief, and it is conjecture.  A conjecture means that the mathematician is not sure if it is true or not.  The twin primes conjecture states that there are an infinite number of twin prime pairs.  Twin primes are prime numbers that differ by two.  If n is the smaller twin then n+2 is the larger of the pair.

Best of luck.
Matt

Comment: Isn't a quite important verb missing in _"... are a number from 0 to 1 that something will happen"_?